# How to bind touchmove in chartjs canvas?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chartjs to draw line charts and can successfully bind onHover but unable to bind touchmove .  From  chartjs documentation (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html#event-option) i can't find a way to bind touchmove.

```
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data,
      legend: { display: false },
      options: {
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false
        }
        onHover: function(event, array = []) {
          if (array?.length) {
            var activeElement = array[0];
            if ("_index" in activeElement) {
              //console.log(activeElement);
              const index = activeElement["_index"];
              const model = activeElement["_model"];
              const xPosition = model["x"];
            }
          }
        }
```

I tried binding mousemove to canvas element(addlistener to canvas dom element) but it desnt contain relevant information(array/events etc) so of no use to me. Any guidance on how to bind touchmove to chartjs canvas element ?

Comment: As it seems you need to add a native 'ontouchmove' event to the canvas element. What you mean it doesn't contain relevant information (array/events etc)?

Comment: @Kostas https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-demo-zau6lb?file=App.jsx   Array logged from mousemove is always empty but when logged through onHover it gets relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the mousemove event to the canvas itself you can get the elements/datasets with the build in methods of chart.js by passing it the event itself.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementatevente

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-demo-zau6lb?file=App.jsx , it always gives [] when logged from mousemove but gives valid info from onHover.

Comment: Is there a way i can attach onMouseMove/ on touchmove to chart ? Like i'm doing onHover ?